# WooCommerce product archive url without value / all values

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, archives

Is is possible to list all products by a certain attribute without specifying the term value ?

Right now, accessing site.com/`attribute_name`/`term_value`/ returns as expected.

Accessing site.com/`attribute_name`/ returns 404

Desired outcome would be listing all products that have `attribute_name`